# Is there any way to programmatically cancel the "slide" animation that occurs when a drag-and-drop operation is canceled?

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, appkit

I'm working on a macOS Qt input plug-in that can trigger a drag-and-drop operation, but does so using events internal to the host application (via Qt's event system). This has caused me to hit a snag where there's a bug when a "mouse down" event is sent through my application while a drag-and-drop sliding animation is in progress, i.e. the animation that occurs when the user releases the mouse during a drag-and-drop without completing it, and the on-screen representation of the drop slides back to its starting point and disappears.

Specifically, sending a mouse down to the application while this sliding animation is in progress only causes the drop to erroneously and suddenly "catch" on to the mouse again, but it's not possible to actually drop it anywhere.

Normally this doesn't happen in macOS because moving the mouse or pressing the mouse button causes the animation to end instantly. But because these mouse events I'm generating are local to my application only, the sliding animation is never canceled.

So I need some way to programmatically cancel it when sending a mouse button down event. I haven't found any way of doing this, though. Is it possible? I'd prefer not to but I'm open to using undocumented APIs and Objective-C method swizzling if need be.

Comment: How do you send the mouse-down events, do you post them or do you send them to a view? Is it a custom drag or a build-in drag like dragging text? Is the drag within the app/window? Is removing all slide-back animations an option? Have you tried stopping the animation by moving the mouse or posting a useless mouse-down event?

Comment: I edited my post a bit to be more clear what's going on. The app is a Qt app, and is using Qt's system. So it's not sending NSEvents into the application event cue. The drags could be any kind: built-in or custom, but they're all started using Apple's standard APIs for drag and drop. I have tried stopping the slide using mouse move events posted to the system, but I haven't been able to get it to work even though natural mouse events do the trick. I want to avoid posting a mouse down event because I can't guarantee it won't have side effects.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found so far is to use `CGEventPost` to post a `kCGEventLeftMouseUp` event at the mouse cursor's current coordinates. This strikes me as troublesome solution because there's no corresponding mouse down event, and an application might respond to it in an undesirable way. I intend to leave this question open in case someone should find a better solution.